# Salesforce Double to Number(16,2)

Tags: apex

I am integrating with an external system trough a REST API. Im bringing in JSON data which I am using to create records of sObjects.

All has been fine and perfect until I had to import a kind of "Invoice/Transaction" object that has a "TotalAmount" field which is a numeric with comma, like "200,50". The thing is that in APEX variables I can hold this as a Integer, Long, Double, etc. 
But the sObject has a type of Number, which I set up as Number(16,2) to have space for 2 digits after the comma.

I have been googling this for a while but found nothing, and I have no idea how to translate the number I bring in my JSON to the Number(16,2) I need to use in my sObject, any clues?

Thanks!

Comment: If the TotalAmount field in the JSON you receive is "200,50" (i.e a string containing a comma as a decimal separator) then you will first have to hold it in a string field and then do your own parsing.

Answer (score 3):

The value you should be using is Decimal, and you can assign the decimal directly to the field when you do so. JSON specifies that numbers must be in a particular, locale-free format.

If you had a class like this:

```
public class InvoiceTransaction {
    public Decimal TotalAmount;
}
```

You could decode your JSON as:

```
InvoiceTransaction thisTransaction = (InvoiceTransaction)JSON.deserialize(jsonString, InvoiceTransaction.class);
```

This lets you assign the value to your field:

myRecord.Total_Amount__c = thisTransaction.TotalAmount;

How it appears in salesforce.com will depend on the user's locale. For example, users set to US locale will show "200.50", while most of Europe will probably show "200,50".

Comment: This is great, I will try it out tomorrow morning :) I will mark it as resolved once I get it working though.
Thanks a lot!